# how to fix this layouts on xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

The thing is, I'm making an app that is available to all iPhones. It's only portrait mode, but I got two issues:

1) The `imageView` on the iPhone 3.5 inch is not resizing (even though I'm using auto layout)

2) I want to make two lines of the `CollectionView` on the iPhone 5.5 inch

Here's the previews:
[image]

Here's the storyboard
[image]

Comment: "The imageView on the iPhone 3.5 inch is not resizing (even though I'm using auto layout" What are you doing that _would_ resize it?

Comment: I'm not doing anything. What should I do?

Comment: If you want a bigger image view, add constraints that would make it bigger.

Comment: I want a smaller imageView, but only on iPhone 3.5 inch. But still, I don't know how to, so if you can answer...

Comment: You cannot make constraints that mean "only on iPhone 3.5 inch".

Comment: maybe a constraint that is proportional to the screen size, I don't know, I hate auto layout

Comment: post the constraints what u have used

Comment: Instead of layout based on the device type, Apple encourages layout based on size classes. These adapt your layout to a general class of length and width

Comment: yeah, but I have no clue how to do that (or anything actually). The only thing I do is "Reset to suggested constraints"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually could solve this by sing more than one Storyboard, each one for one device. It's not Apple's recommendation, but it works fine when you have to display on many devices, and it's way easier than auto layout.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-a-different-storyboard-depending-on-screen-size-in-ios/).